# How to pattern the string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to pattern the string like this:

```
letters (in here there may be letters, numbers and whitespace)
```

I have try for this but it doesn't work.

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
String format = "^[a-zA-Z]* ([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]*)$";
String userInput = cin.nextLine();
if (userInput.matches(format)) {
   System.out.println("Correct Patten");
} else {
   System.out.println("Incorrect Pattern");
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the exact string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some characters in regex has special meaning, parenthesis is one of them. For them ot be interpreted as a character you need to escape them with a backslash, and since backslash has a special meaning in java strings you need to escape that with a backslash (for a total of two).

So your regex should be

```
String format = "^[a-zA-Z]* \\([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s]*\\)$";
```

Comment: oh... thanks sir, It works now. I have tried with backslash but opposite you.

Answer (score 3):

A parenthesis in regex has special meaning and you need to match the literal character. Escape both parens by preceding them with a double backslash.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that you need to escape the escape char :-D

Answer (score 1):

escape your brackets with backslashes and also you are missing a comma in your format:

```
`String format ="^[a-zA-Z]*\\s\\([a-zA-Z_0-9\\s,]*\\)";`

        String userInput = cin.nextLine();
System.out.println(userInput);
        if(userInput.matches(format)){

           System.out.println("Correct Patten");

        }else{

           System.out.println("Incorrect Pattern");

        }

    INPUT: letters (in here there may be letters, numbers and whitespace)
    OUTPUT:correct Pattern
```

Comment: hum, I can see the space in the question, how is it missing

Comment: @eis what i meant was he was missing the space in the input